# Set format of the document as the format for the listing

Tags: formatting, listings, fontsize, lstdefinestyle

I would like to set the text format of the document as the format for the listing. The words in the listing accross my tex document have a bigger space between the characters. I want them to the have the exact format and size as the normal text(the only exception is the keywords). Can anyone give me some hints? Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{listings}



\lstdefinelanguage{sparql} {
morekeywords={LIMIT, PREFIX, GRAPH, AS, WITH, RECURSIVE, CONSTRUCT, FROM, NAMED, SELECT, WHERE, DISTINCT, FILTER, ORDER, BY, ASC, REGEX, DSC},
sensitive=true
}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=sparql}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:rdf-rdfs-example, captionpos=b, caption=N-Triple illustration for the Figure \ref{fig:RDF-RDFS}, basicstyle=\small,float,floatplacement=H]

PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/>

RDFS: 
<http://example.com/person> <rdfs:subClassOf> <http://example.com/customer> . 
<http://example.com/laptop> <rdfs:subClassOf> <http://example.com/product> .
<http://example.com/hasBought> <rdfs:domain> <http://example.com/person> .
<http://example.com/hasBought> <rdfs:range> <http://example.com/product> .

RDF: 

<http://example.com/persons/1> <rdf:type> <http://example.com/customer> .
<http://example.com/laptops/2> <rdf:type> <http://example.com/laptop> .
<http://example.com/persons/1> ex:hasBought <http://example.com/laptops/2> .
\end{lstlisting}
\section{RDF Frameworks} 
The two major RDF frameworks that have been used for the evaluations presented in this Thesis are Jena \cite{carroll2004jena} and Sesame \cite{broekstra2002sesame} (recently known as RDF4J \footnote{\url{http://rdf4j.org}}). They are both Java frameworks for storing and querying RDF data and consist of parsers and writers for most types of RDF serializations.
\end{document}
```

[image: example page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing in `listings` is determined by the column alignment (as described in section 2.10 of the documentation). So you can use the `columns=fullflexible` to achieve the look you want:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}

\lstdefinelanguage{sparql} {
morekeywords={LIMIT, PREFIX, GRAPH, AS, WITH, RECURSIVE, CONSTRUCT, FROM, NAMED, SELECT, WHERE, DISTINCT, FILTER, ORDER, BY, ASC, REGEX, DSC},
sensitive=true,
columns=fullflexible
}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=sparql}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:rdf-rdfs-example, captionpos=b, caption=N-Triple illustration for the Figure \ref{fig:RDF-RDFS}, basicstyle=\small,float,floatplacement=H]

PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/>

RDFS: 
<http://example.com/person> <rdfs:subClassOf> <http://example.com/customer> . 
<http://example.com/laptop> <rdfs:subClassOf> <http://example.com/product> .
<http://example.com/hasBought> <rdfs:domain> <http://example.com/person> .
<http://example.com/hasBought> <rdfs:range> <http://example.com/product> .


\end{lstlisting}
\section{RDF Frameworks} 
The two major RDF frameworks that have been used for the evaluations presented in this Thesis are Jena \cite{carroll2004jena} and Sesame \cite{broekstra2002sesame} (recently known as RDF4J \footnote{\url{http://rdf4j.org}}). They are both Java frameworks for storing and querying RDF data and consist of parsers and writers for most types of RDF serializations.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]